# How to use rappid.js & joint.js with angular 2?

Tags: angular, jointjs, rappid

I want to use rappid and joint.js inside one of component of my angular 2 application.

I have tried googling it, but didn't find a example which serves my purpose. Is there demo example or way which demonstrate how it can be used ?

Answer (score 0):

I created a demo for getting this to work.
It's in the answer here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50195154/4704261